# Error in ('str' object has no attribute 'iloc')

Tags: pandas, anaconda, jupyter

I have this code that I'm working on but I'm getting an error

The code:

```
for dataset in train_data:
    dataset.iloc[dataset['Age'] <= 20, 'Age'] = 1,
    dataset.iloc[(dataset['Age'] > 20, 'Age') & (dataset['Age'] <= 40), 'Age'] = 2,
    dataset.iloc[dataset['Age'] > 40, 'Age'] = 3
```

The error:
'str' object has no attribute 'iloc'

What should I change to resolve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: The error suggests that dataset is a string. Double-check the contents of dataset and train_data.

Comment: can you please give a description of your variables, I get the impression that your train_data is a list of dataframes, but it is clearly not since the error points clearly that the elements of train_data are strings. Can you please double check, and update your question with the type of your data.

Comment: What is `train_data`? We can't help if we don't know, and apparently you don't either (otherwise you wouldn't get an error like this)

Comment: If `train_data` is a pandas dataframe the `for dataset in train_data` will iterate through the column names of `train_data`, not the values, and thus give you a string and this error.

Answer (score 0):

We can force the type of the column `age` to be `float` and then use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to get the expected result :

```py
import numpy as np


dataset['Age'] = dataset['Age'].astype(float)

condlist = [dataset['Age'] <= 20, 
            (dataset['Age'] > 20, 'Age') & (dataset['Age'] <= 40), 
            dataset['Age'] > 40]

choicelist = [1, 2, 3]            

dataset['Age'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default=np.nan)
```

Comment: there's no need to use the for loop for changing the column type, please review your code, it's misleading.

Comment: Hi Youssef, thanks for your comment, I updated the answer :)

Comment: we can't know if your solution is the right one or not, the question isn't clear enough to give a solution